# CPU struggling, but not really?

Tags: cpu, motherboard, performance

I have two very similar PCs, both with Intel Core i7 3770 CPU, both with a B75 Chipset, both with 16GB of 1600MHz RAM (one with two 8 GB sticks, other with four 4 GB sticks) on Dual Channel, both with SSD, both with GTX 970 Graphics, but they don't perform similarly at all.

One of them struggles a lot to run games, and apparently the bottleneck is the CPU, as it accuses high CPU use. Already inverted the CPUs of the two PCs, the graphics cards too, and the problem persists. Reinstalled Windows many times, updated BIOS, nothing seems to fix this bug.

The only real difference between them is the Motherboard, one uses an Asus P8B75-M LE and the other (the bad one) a GigaByte GA-B75M-D3H, but as you can see the Chipset is the same, so I suppose there is no reason for them to perform differently, or is there?

Now with the release of Cyberpunk 2077 I was delighted to see that this dinosaur still got it, but of course it's retarded clone don't. I'm considering replacing this Motherboard, but I'd like some opinions before spending the money, does anyone here knows what might be going on?

Comment: BIOS up to date on both motherboards?

Comment: Yeap, been over all that...

Comment: Rather than swapping the hardware pieces.. have you tried swapping the drive?  What happens then?  Have you confirmed that the UEFI firmware (wrongly aka BIOS) settings are the same between the two machines?

Comment: Different motherboards, but, yeah I made sure the RAM clock is right, that it is using AHCI, dual-channel, all the good stuff. Does it matter if it's using UEFI or not?

Comment: Oh, another thing I just realized, even though they both have 16GB RAM, one is 8+8 but the other is 4+4+4+4, wonder if this could interfere?

Comment: Why have you decided that the bottleneck is the CPU?

Comment: Because it accuses high CPU use.

Comment: Check the windows power profile, set it to high performance on each and see if it makes a difference.

Answer (score -1):

I looked up some details on both of those motherboards, to see if I could find anything that may help... here is what I found, hopefully it might help:

First, I looked up each motherboard and looked at the specs on each companies website ([GigaByte](https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/GA-B75M-D3H-rev-10#ov) and [Asus](https://www.asus.com/us/Motherboards/P8B75M_LE/)). I was comparing the specs for each one but couldn't seem to find anything that wasn't "compatible". I then realized that on the GigaByte page, they didn't say what CPUs were compatible (the Asus page did).

I then looked up the GigaByte motherboard on [UserBenchmark](https://www.userbenchmark.com/System/Gigabyte-GA-B75M-D3H/3837), and I noticed that it doesn't show 4x4GB under RAM... does the computer with the GigaByte motherboard have the 4x4GB RAM in it? If it does, I would try switching it with the 2x8GB, and try that.
If you are interested, [here](https://www.userbenchmark.com/System/Asus-P8B75-M-LE/776) is the UserBenchmark for the Asus motherboard...